# image works in a vue component and doesn't in another

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuetify.js

So i have a vue component in blade file (am using laravel), the component display all the images with a v-for using data that are being fetched with axios while the second display only one image with data that is passed through a prop.
The issue i have is that the src in the v-img (am also using vuetify) works in the first component but doesnt in the second even though the links are the same and both component are called in blade file situated in the same folder.
here's the code :
the show all images blade file :

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div id="app">
      <show-images></show-images> 
</div>
@endsection
```

The show-images vue file :

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <v-layout row wrap>
            <v-flex 
            xs12 sm6 md4 lg3
            v-for="image in images" :key="image.id"
            >
            <a :href="'images/' + image.id">
            <v-card
            shaped
            hover

            class="text-center mx-3 my-3">

            <v-responsive class="pt-4">
                <v-img
                lazy-src="https://via.placeholder.com/300?text=Something+Went+Wrong"
                aspect-ratio="1"
                src="blue-hole.jpg"
                ></v-img>
            </v-responsive>

            <v-card-text>
                <div class="subheading">{{image.title}}</div>
            </v-card-text>

            </v-card>
            </a>
            </v-flex>


        </v-layout>



   <div class="text-center">
    <v-pagination
      v-model="pagination.current"
      :length="pagination.total"
      @input="onPageChange"
      color="white"
      dark
    ></v-pagination>
  </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data(){
        return{
            images:[],
            pagination: {
                current: 1,
                total: 0
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        getImages(){
            axios.get('api/getImages?page=' + this.pagination.current)
            .then(response => {
            this.images = response.data.data;
            this.pagination.current = response.data.current_page;
            this.pagination.total = response.data.last_page;
            });
        },
        onPageChange(){
            this.getImages();
            window.scrollTo(0,0);
        },
        showImage(id){
            console.log(id)
            axios.get('api/showimage/' + id)
        }


    },
    mounted(){
            this.getImages();
            console.log('sup')
    }
}
</script>
```

The show single image blade file :

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div id="app">
    <show-image :image = '@json($image)'></show-image>
</div>
@endsection
```

and here's the show-image vue file :

```
<template>

    <div>

        <h1 class="subheading gre--text">test</h1>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row" style="height:100%;border:2px solid blue">
                <div class="col-sm-5" style="border:2px solid red">

                        <v-card flat class="text-center mx-2 my-2">
                            <v-responsive class="pt-4">
                                <v-img
                                lazy-src="https://via.placeholder.com/300?text=Something+Went+Wrong"
                                aspect-ratio="1"
                                src="blue-hole.jpg" 
                                ></v-img>
                            </v-responsive>
                            <v-card-text>
                                <!-- <div class="subheading"> {{image.title}} </div> -->
                                <div class="grey--text"> {{image.file_name}} </div>
                            </v-card-text>
                            <v-card-actions>
                                <v-btn color="grey">
                                    <v-icon left small>mdi-download-outline</v-icon>
                                    <span>Download</span>
                                </v-btn>
                            </v-card-actions>
                        </v-card>

                </div>

            </div>


        </div>




    </div>

</template>


<script>
export default {
    props : [
        'image'
    ],
    data(){
        return{

        }
    },
}
</script>
```

I even tried using img tag, thought it was a vuetify bug but the problem remains. Please help.
Thanks !
ps : the blue-hole.jpg is situated in the public folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, enclose your `@json(image)` directive with double quotes:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div id="app">
    <show-image :image="{{ json_encode($image) }}"></show-image>
</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: if i do so, it dislays the image data in json form instead of displaying the vue.js component

Comment: @RyadSn I updated my answer. Also, can you do a `console.log(this.image)` on component mount and paste your result here?

Comment: i've already did this with my version and it showed the exact same thing, here's the result  of {{ json_encode($image) }} : {id: 2, title: "118637_adapted_720x1280", file_name: "118637-adapted-720x1280-1590519216.jpg", description: "qsqs qd qsd qs d", category1: "abstract", …}
category1: "abstract"
category2: "null"
created_at: "2020-05-26 18:53:36"
description: "qsqs qd qsd qs d"
file_name: "118637-adapted-720x1280-1590519216.jpg"
id: 2
title: "118637_adapted_720x1280"
updated_at: "2020-05-26 18:53:36"
__proto__: Object

Comment: even though i don't think the problem's here, it's just that the src in the v-img not working.